# Minecraft launcher problems

Tags: java, launcher, minecraft

I run a minecraft server for my family. I also run a client from the same machine. the client all of a sudden gets stuck on "preparing" for the newest version. old versions work fine.
so i tried the new laucher and it is giving me the following error log.
Any help would really be appreciated ive been trying to fix this all day for my kids.

Thanks

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f089b88b940, pid=7273, tid=0x00007f089c11a700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_222-b10) (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.222-b10 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x16e940]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/tinbash/snap/mc-installer/410/.minecraft/hs_err_pid7273.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Launcher got stuck on Preparing.  My error log looks different, but it seems to be the same issue.  Workaround: I'm running Linux Mint, and the software manager has 2 versions of Minecraft.  The regular one and the flathub version.  I tried deleting and re-installing the regular one - no joy.  Deleted the regular one and installed flathub version (takes a bit of time).  That one works for me.  HOWEVER, the flathub version puts the files in a different place, and when I loaded it up all the old worlds were missing.  Created a new flathub world (with a unique) name, and then searched to find the new directory.  Copied worlds from old place to new, and I think it is good (had to reset controls though).  I think I like the flathub laucher better anyway -Bonus!- although you need to look at the options in the various menus.